# Redirect root domain homepage to another domain subdirectory

Tags: redirect, seo, migration

I would like to:

- Redirect www.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com/page
- Redirect www.olddomain.com/article1 to www.newdomain.com/article1

Here is what I put into my htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/page
redirect 301 /article1/ http://www.newdomain.com/article1
```

The first redirect works, however, the second one does NOT work, since www.olddomain.com/article1 redirects to www.newdomain.com/page/article1, which does not exist and thus returns a 404 error.

How to redirect the old domain home page (root) to a new domain subdirectory, without affecting all other redirects?

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess code should look like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.newdomain.com/page [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/article1/$ http://www.newdomain.com/article1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marcin. However, even after a couple of attempts, this code did not work.

When I say that is does not work, I mean that the redirect are not taken into account: the old website still appears when we connect to the old domain.

Where should be place the .htaccess on the server: in the root of the server (outside the www directory) or in the root of the website (inside the www directory)?

Comment: It should be placed in www directory. If your site main file (usually index.php) is in directory whatever/domain/public.html/ you should place in this file your .htaccess file. What URL you are testing? You should test http://example.com/article1/ and http://example.com/ - with trailing slashes